# issues installing and running Dataloader on my MacOS Big Sur

Tags: data-loader

please I am having issues installing and running Dataloader on my MacOS Big Sur.
I have downloaded and installed Zulu.
I have also downloaded and installed Dataloader but when I run it, I get the error: DATALOADER_WORK_DIRECTORY_PLACEHOLDER: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to access jarfile dataloader-52.0.0-uber.jar
How do I fix this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences ->Security&Privacy ->Privacy ->Full disk access and Files and Folders and add Zulu java to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is I can't select the whole zulu folder so what file in the folder do I select?

Comment: The java executable

Comment: The java executable files are greyed out. I can't select them.

Comment: Yay! I found a solution. I follow these steps exactly. Scroll down to the section "Running Data Loader on Mac M1 Hardware" (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_install_mac.htm). I tried these steps before but for reason, they worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Directory in which you have the Dataloader folder.
then on the terminal run below command -

```
chmod 777 YourDataLoaderFolderName
```

For example, if my Dataloader folder is on Desktop it will be like this -

```
Desktop %     chmod 777 dataloader_mac
```